# evaluation of word2vec-cosine similarity

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I used a word2vec algorithm to compute document in a vector.I want to calculate the RMSE for different threshod.

code:

```
    def tokenize(line: String): Seq[String] = {
    line.split("""\W+""")
        .map(_.toLowerCase)
        .filter(token => regex.pattern.matcher(token).matches)
        .filterNot(token => stopwords.contains(token))
        .filterNot(token => rareTokens.contains(token))
        .filter(token => token.size >=2)
        .toSeq
}
val tokens = text.map(doc => tokenize(doc))
import org.apache.spark.mllib.feature.Word2Vec
val word2vec = new Word2Vec()
word2vec.setSeed(42) // we do this to generate the same results each time
val word2vecModel = word2vec.fit(tokens)
val synonyms = word2vecModel.findSynonyms("drama", 15)
    for((synonym, cosineSimilarity) <- synonyms) {
      println(s"$synonym $cosineSimilarity")
    }
 val MSE =  synonyms .map { case (v, p) => math.pow((v - p), 2) }.mean() 
val RMSE:Double=math.sqrt(MSE)
println("RMSE:"+RMSE)
```

when measuring RMSE,this error appear.

```
value - is not a member of String
```

How to solve it?

Comment: In `case (v, p)` the `v` type is `String` so `v - p` is meaningless because you can't subtract from a `String`.

Comment: ok, can I put v as long value to measure RMSE?